# Scroll window onclick jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, scrolltop

I have this code for my sliding footer. When I make it visible via the #sod-drawer-handle, it slides down. However the window does not scroll down the -handle is clicked. How could I do this as easy as possible?

I have read up on it, but I am not sure what selector to use.

```
if(jQuery('#sod-drawer-plugin.bottom').length >0){

    jQuery('#sod-drawer-plugin.bottom #sod-drawer-handle').click(function(){

       jQuery('#sod-drawer-plugin.bottom .content').slideToggle();

    });
```

I would greatly appriciate any hint or help I can get.

Comment: Do you even know what `slideToggle` does?

Comment: I guess you need scrollTop??

Answer (score 1):

Use something such as this to scroll the window down.

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:200});
```

This will scroll the window down 200px.